# Problemas com CI/CD nas Actions do Github para o AWS

Tags: amazon-aws, pipeline, github

Estou enfrentando um problema ao fazer o CD da minha aplicação no AWS, dentro do meu código yml tenho o seguinte trecho:

```
# Configure AWS credentials
- name: Configure AWS credentials
   uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
   with:
     aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
     aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
     aws-region: us-east-1
```

Porém recebo o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro do meu projeto do GitHub tenho os secrets desta forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz algumas pesquisas porém não consegui descobrir o motivo, além disso fiz um teste passando os secrets direto no código para testar o CD e funcionou corretamente, estou esquecendo de fazer alguma configuração?

Comment: O nome da sua variável está errado. Está faltando o sufixo: `_ID`. Na variável `secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. Deveria ser:  `${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}`.

Comment: nossa não acredito que dei esse mole, muito obrigado.